# Interaction between two UIViewControllers on one screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

[image]

I apologize for not actually screenshotting my storyboard on XCode. This is a Microsoft Paint rendition of the storyboard. Basically I want to be able to do something as simple as click the "Say Hello!" button on the main view controller and change the label in the panel view controller to say "Hello!" I've tried the process listed out on numerous StackOverflow posts and [this article](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) but I think I am missing something because it flat out does not work. I think there should be a segue between the main view controller and panel view controller but don't know which way to turn it and what type to use.

For what it is worth, I am using the [ARSlidingPanel](https://github.com/andriirogulin/ARSlidingPanel) library to get the desired layout that I need. The only problem is now I can't interact between the two view controllers.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are in main view controller, you can get the object of container. while loading the panel view controller you must have created its object in container. so from main view controller you can acess this object of panel view controller and all of its properties. for example :

in main VC

```
container = self.parentViewController;
container.panel.label.text = @"some text";
```

where panel is the property in container controller of panel view controller type.

Comment: So simple! I'll try this when I get back to my Mac. Thanks

Comment: please let me know if it works for you problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Beautiful! Works great. Thank you :)